# Retrieving last 5 records in database

Tags: php, html, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Morning All,

I have a table which lists the amount of jobs by a department for each week of the year, I'm then trying to output these results in a table in PHP. However, I need the table to show only the last 5 weeks of the year based on the date of accessing, so for example, we are currently in week 23 so it would be showing weeks, 22,21,20,19 & 18.

I've created a table in PHP like so...

```
Dept  | week 1 | week 2 | week 3 | week 4  | week 5

 A1   |   5    |   6    |    7   |   8     |   9

 B1   |   6    |   7    |    8   |   7     |   8
```

I'm running the following query...

```
select *
from (select * from OPEN_JOBS order by week DESC)
WHERE rownum <= 5
order by week
```

This brings the results out like this

```
a1  |  b1  |  week

5   |   6  |   1

6   |   7  |   2
```

I'm not entirely sure of the best way to action this query to display them withing the php table, I was thinking of running 5 separate queries that show each of the last 5 weeks, is that possible?

Comment: Instead of your current query, couldn't you just query: `SELECT * FROM OPEN_JOBS WHERE rownum <= 5 ORDER BY week DESC`? Currently you're doing `SELECT *` and `ORDER BY week` twice.

Comment: Please share more details, like a larger set of input data

Comment: That won't work, @Daan. WHERE clause is executed before ORDER BY so your suggestion won't produce correct result.

Comment: Is your question "my SQL query doesn't return what I expect" - if so, please post sample data and expected output. Or is your question "how do I turn the rows in my query results into columns in PHP"?

Answer (score 0):

Query you wrote looks OK. Alternatively, you might use `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function but the result should be the same.

```
select x.*
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (order by week desc) rn
      from open_jobs o
     )
where x.rn <= 5
order by week
```